# What is the difference between using a node module directly and creating an object of the node module then using it?

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to interact with the [fabric-client](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/release-1.4/fabric-client)node module. I am unable to figure out how to use certain methods.

```
const FabricClient = require('fabric-client'); 
const clientObject = new FabricClient();
```

Here clientObject allows me to access some functions that are not available to FabricClient. My understanding is that maybe because Client.js extends BaseClient.js (which I am assuming is what is imported throught the node module as FabricClient), the clientObject allows me to call functions that are a part of Client.js and BaseClient.js.

But if that is correct, by that same logic, how do I access functions from Config.js or CertifcateAuthority.js?

Could someone explain what is happening in the background and how can I determine which functions can be called through my app?

Comment: It's in the hands of those who write the libraries, they are free to do as they see fit.
You will have to check each doc to make sure how to properly use each lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are importing the node module you are importing the object from the library. When you use the new keyword and assigning it to a variable, you are creating a new instance of it. Meaning another copy. It depends on how the code is written to determine if you need to make a new instance of it or not.